# Simple Test Mockito on Android is failing

Tags: android, mockito, junit4

Can anyone tell me why this Test is failing and/or how to get the test running?

The Test runs correctly until the last assertion.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AccountHelpTest {

    @Mock
    AccountManager accountManager;

    public class AccountHelp {
        public AccountManager accountManager;
        public Account[] getAccounts(String type) {
            return accountManager.getAccountsByType(type);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void account() {
        AccountHelp ah = new AccountHelp();
        ah.accountManager = accountManager;

        when(accountManager.getAccountsByType(anyString())).thenReturn(new Account[]{new Account("name", "type")});

        Account[] types = ah.getAccounts("type");

        Assert.assertNotNull(types);

        Assert.assertEquals(1, types.length);

        Assert.assertEquals("name", types[0].name);
    }
}
```

I could break it down to this problem:

```
Account account = new Account("name", "test");
Assert.assertEquals("name", account.name);
```

This is failing! (its a JUnit4 Test, not an instrumentationTest)

Comment: Show your Account class.

Comment: It's the Android Account Class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html)

Here's the code:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/accounts/Account.java#Account

Answer (score 0):

It turnes out that Android Studio [provides a special android.jar](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) for testing, which enables i.e. Mockito to work.
All classes in this jar are some kind of dummy classes, which is the reason why the test fails.

As a solution (depending on what you want to test) you could just create your own implementation of the classes you want to use. In my class it would be something like this:

```
package android.accounts;

public class Account {
    public final String type;
    public final String name;

    public Account(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

after creating this and executing the tests again, the test succeed.

Answer (score 0):

As Unicate said, Android Studio provides an android.jar in which all methods are stubs. [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) is made to handle this by producing working mock classes that substitute for Android's built ins. They substitute [`ShadowAccountManager`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/2.4/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAccountManager.html) for `AccountManager`.

Personally, I find the documentation for their new version to be frustratingly sparse, but maybe you will have better luck than I.